# Segmentation fault 11 errors everywhere in Swift 3 migration

Tags: ios, segmentation-fault, migration, swift3

Trying to migrate to Swift 3.0. I seem to be getting Segmentation fault 11 errors everywhere. Has anyone else encountered this? No idea how to find out what is causing the issue. If I try to open a file that the error is reported to be in and commenting out code bit by bit it make no difference. Can't seem to isolate anything. Any tips on how to fix this? Also examining the file will often cause the syntax highlighting to turn off and Xcode will report a limited functionality error. How can I fix this? Even if I comment ALL the methods and vars out of the particular file I still get the Segmentation fault 11 on compile.

Comment: Segmentation fault 11 often appears when there is a non type-safe implementation. It happened to me in Swift 2 as well. There should be a note from XCode, at the end of that long error log that is displayed when you click on the "Segmentation fault 11" error message, that points you to the class and the line number that violates type-safe Swift requirement(s).

Comment: No error message for me. I have tried commenting out the methods one by one. Also commenting out all the methods and the vars but it still returns the segmentation error.

Comment: @Kex well some piece of code is causing this. In some cases there is in that long Segmentation fault 11 error message a line that tells you where error happened. Search through, if there isn't any you should comment code piece by piece and figure out what is causing it.

Comment: I doubt we can help you further without code :(